# Event Handler is Always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling, null

I have searched extensively on this, but cannot find the solution to my problem. I am trying to call a function in the code behind of a page from a user control on that page.

I have a web application that uses a master page. I am adding a user control that I wrote to one of the content pages. I added the user control to the aspx page by dragging and dropping it from the toolbox. I am able to see the user control from the code behind, but I cannot access the public functions. To fix that problem, I created an object of the user control in the code behind and used the LoadControl function. All of that seems to work fine.

The problem I am having is when I am trying to hook the into the EventHandler from the aspx page to the user control. Everything compiles and runs just fine, but I am not seeing anything happen on the page. I think the issue is that the EventHandler is always null.

User Control Code

```
public partial class ucBuyerList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate void BuyerSelectedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event BuyerSelectedEventHandler BuyerSelected;

    private string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string auid = "";
    public string AUID
    {
        get { return auid; }
        set { auid = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnBuyerSelected(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BuyerSelected != null)
        {
            BuyerSelected(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void lbBuyerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetNameAndAUID();
        OnBuyerSelected(e);
    }

    private void SetNameAndAUID()
    {
        name = lbBuyerList.SelectedItem.Text;
        auid = lbBuyerList.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

Parent Page Code

```
    public partial class frmBuyerInformation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.changePageTitle("Buyer Information");
        buyerList.BuyerSelected += new ucBuyerList.BuyerSelectedEventHandler(buyerListControl_BuyerSelected);
    }

    void buyerListControl_BuyerSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayBuyerInformation();
    }

    public void DisplayBuyerInformation()
    {
        tbName.Text = buyerList.Name;
        tbAUID.Text = buyerList.AUID;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: This issue has been resolved. The code snippits above are now functional. If anyone runs into the issue I had, you can model the code above. Make sure that `AutoEventWireup="true"` in both the aspx and ascx pages. Thank you June Paik for your solution. Thank you Diego De Vita for your input as well.

Comment: `if (BuyerSelected != null) { BuyerSelected(this, e); }` Do not ever do this!  This code creates a race condition.  This is the proper idiom: `var h = BuyerSelected; if (h != null) h(this, e);`

Comment: I wrote something else just few seconds ago..sorry..actually I saw your comment and maybe I don't agree. I always fire event class that way. It means: call event handlers in case there are any attached to the event. now I didn't read carefully the question so I have no answer. Just saying that your last comment is not correct

Comment: I wonder if you really declared lbBuyerList_SelectedIndexChanged as the handler of such an event on the asp.net control modifying the proper tag attribute declaratively in the ascx. You may try using breakpoints on each stage (starting from the body of that method) and discover during debug if that code is called.

Comment: I did make sure the list box has declared lbBuyerList_SelectedIndexChanged as the handler. I also confirmed that the code is being executed. I put a breakpoint on the if(BuyerSelected != null) line of code and I see that the BuyerSelected is always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with events for quite a while as well. Nowadays I always create them this way 'cause it's the only way I know it works. Haven't tested it with your code but here it goes anyway:

```
public partial class ucBuyerList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate void BuyerSelectedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event BuyerSelectedEventHandler BuyerSelected;

    public string Name;
    public string AUID;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Select the first buyer in the list when the user control loads

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lbBuyerList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnBuyerSelected(EventArgs e)
    {
        BuyerSelectedEventHandler handler = BuyerSelected;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void lbBuyerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Name = lbBuyerList.SelectedItem.Text;
        AUID = lbBuyerList.SelectedItem.Value;
        OnBuyerSelected(e);
    }
}
```

In the parent page you can just call your function the same way you're doing it already.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. I attempted to use this code but I still find that the "handler" object is null.

Comment: This is a wild guess though, but have you tried wrapping your parent's page page_load in an if(!Page.IsPostback) ?

Comment: I changed my code to use the method that you described above. It did not work at first. I had to make the AutoEventWireup="true" in both the aspx and ascx pages. Thank you very much for your help. I will post the code for others to use if they run into a situation like I did.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `Page_Load` is too late in the page lifecycle to be using LoadControl and subscribing to the event.  What happens if you move that code to the `Page_Init` method?

Comment: that could be a good point. Usually I add user controls on the declarative ascx, not programmatically.